# How to see which package depends on the lib?

Tags: linux, package-management

I come with a question - how to check which package depends on a given lib? I don't mean `apt show [lib]` because that shows what dependencies are responsible for a particular lib. And I have a lib (after a system update) and I don't know which package depends on that lib and if I have anything to worry about/need to replace it.

System: Ubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `apt-rdepends` package, available from the Universe  repository  on Ubuntu. Install it via:

```
sudo apt install apt-rdepends
```

To check the reverse dependencies on a specific package or library (runtime or development packages), you may  invoke the command as such:

```
apt-rdepends -r package_name
```

More documentation on the same can be viewed on the manpage [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/apt-rdepends.1.html).

If you require a dependency graph output viewable via the [dot](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dot) application, you may also use the `debtree` package, installed via:

```
sudo apt install debtree
```

Via the arguments `--show-rdeps`,  equivalent to `-R`, as [documented](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/debtree.1.html) in the man pages.

**A few examples:**

1. Create a .dot file (a [directed graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirectedGraph.html) drawing):

`debtree --show-rdeps package_name >out.dot`

2. Create a graph (PNG) from a .dot file:

`dot -T png -o out.png out.dot`

3. Create a graph (Postscript) and view it using [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/):

`debtree package_name | dot -Tps | okular - &`

Comment: rich answer, thanks!